# Sliding Menu not opening on swipe

Tags: android

I am trying to use the `Sliding Menu` [Library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/) in my app but I am having a problem getting it to slide with my finger. I can get it to open if I call the `toggle()` method which I cann when the `home` icon is pressed or if I `slide my finger across the ActionBar` but if I slide my finger to open it where all the content is, nothing happens

this is my activity

```
public class SmsActivity extends SlidingActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state){
    super.onCreate(state);
    setContentView(R.layout.sms_layout);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    view = i.getIntExtra("sms_view", 1);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    bar.setIcon(R.drawable.menu_button);
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.sms_menu_layout);

    SlidingMenu menu = getSlidingMenu();
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);

}
```

The menu should open up a `PreferenceFragment` and the content is just a `ListFragment`

here is the XML for that activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment android:id="@+id/sms_frame"
    android:name="com.app.notifyme.Fragments.ContactListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried following the example and I dont see anything different from what I have so I dont know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: tyczj, I had exactly the same issue! Lost 1 working day fighting it, but no luck. Sample project works well so I decided just to 'refactor' it rather than writing from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting setClickable(true) for view that you return from onCreateView in Fragment.

Comment: The fragment is just a `ListFragment` so I dont Override `onCreateView` as there really is no layout to return

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be missing these 2 lines:

```
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
menu.setMenu(R.layout.sm_app);
```

These connect your SlidingMenu to your Activity - you aren't seeing the menu, because it isn't attached.

Comment: those are used when you extend `Activity` I am extending `SliderActivity`. If I put those lines in i get errors saying activity is already attached and duplicate xml found

Comment: OK, sorry.  I don't extend SliderActivity, so don't know.  I extend SherlockActivity.

Comment: Well either way if I change it to activity and add those lines I still get the same result

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and I fix it with:

```
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
```

instead of

```
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
```

Example:

```
menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);

menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.bg_menu_shadow);
menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.bg_shadow_width);

menu.setBehindScrollScale(0.0f);
menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
```

Take care